# Remove an action - Wordpress (Specifically Woocommerce PIP plugin)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have Woocommerce website with the plugin Print Invoices/Packing Lists installed.

I'm trying to remove an action and I've narrowed down the action to this (shortened) code;

```
class WC_PIP_Document_Invoice extends WC_PIP_Document {
    public function __construct( array $args ) {
        parent::__construct( $args );

        // add a "View Invoice" link on order processing/complete emails sent to customer
        add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', array( $this, 'order_paid_email_view_invoice_link' ), 40, 3 );
    }
}
```

So I'm looking at removing this using; https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

However as the action as added within a class, I can't quite work out what to pass into the function name. Would it be something like;

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', array( 'WC_PIP_Document_Invoice', 'order_paid_email_view_invoice_link' ), 40 );
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code that should work for you.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_106269_remove_hooks', 11 );
function wpse_106269_remove_hooks(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'action_woocommerce_email_order_meta', 10, 4 ); 
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code isn't working for me. I'm also trying to remove the action like the original poster.